# Into how many languages has the Pearl of Great Price and the Doctrines and Covenants been translated?

Tags: lds, doctrine-and-covenants, pearl-of-great-price

The Bible is by far the most translated book in the world at over 470 languages.  Another question asks specifically about the Book of Mormon, which has apparently been translated into 82 languages.

The LDS Church recognizes the Pearl of Great Price and the Doctrines and Covenants as Scripture as well.  In fact, they seem to contain the primary basis for many of the doctrines that are exclusive to the LDS.

So, what are the translation statistics for these works?

Comment: Given that this question was asked a year ago, I'm not sure if I should bother adding a new answer, but this page has up-to-date statistics: http://scripturetools.net/availability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was going to make this a comment, but it's much too long. I couldn't find official statistics, but I think this is enough to offer as an answer:

Based upon what is currently available, the Pearl of Great Price and Doctrine and Covenants can be [purchased separately](http://store.lds.org/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product3_715839595_10557_3074457345616706323_-1__195911) in the following **11 languages**:

```
Afrikaans
Arabic
Armenian West
Catalan
Croatian
English Braille
Fijian
Greek
Polish
Rarotongan
Tahitian
```

However, the Pearl of Great Price and Doctrine and Covenants are much more typically combined with The Book of Mormon as the [Triple Combination](http://store.lds.org/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product3_715839595_10557_3074457345616706311_-1__195551) available in the following **33 languages**:

```
Albanian
Armenian East
Bulgarian
Cebuano
Chinese
Chinese (Simplified)
Danish
Dutch
English
Fante
Finnish
French
German
Haitian
Hungarian
Icelandic
Igbo
Ilokano
Indonesian
Italian
Latvian
Lithuanian
Mongolian
Norwegian
Pangasinan
Portuguese
Romanian
Shona
Spanish
Swedish
Tagalog
Ukrainian
Vietnamese
```

By addition, (there are no exact duplicates) both books are currently available from LDS Distribution in **44 languages**. By no means does this mean it is not available at least in part in other languages (LDS.org now serves content in your choice of 100 languages, most of which I do not understand).

Answer (score 3):

I could not track down an exact answer for the number of languages that the Pearl of Great Price and the Doctrines and Covenants is currently translated in. In a General Conference talk in 1972, one speaker reported: "The translation and distribution in our day are directed by John E. Carr. He and his able assistants have charge of warehousing and distributing all of the English materials as well as having the responsibility of translating, printing, warehousing, and distributing the non-English materials of the Church throughout the world. To accomplish this task of bringing these hundreds of items to those who require them, members of the Church are working in twenty-eight languages that reach sixty countries." (https://www.lds.org/general-conference/1972/04/the-fullness-of-the-gospel-in-each-mans-language?lang=eng&query=available+languages)

However, I'm sure that the number of languages has grown. The bi-annual General Conference broadcast by the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints is: "Today interpretation is offered in 93 languages both from Salt Lake City and remotely." https://www.lds.org/church/news/translation-division-marks-50-years-of-providing-interpretation-at-general-conference?lang=eng&query=translation+of+doctrine+and+covenants+into+other+languages

There are many efforts to translate all scriptures into a language people can understand. One reason is listed in the Doctrine and Covenants: "For it shall come to pass in that day, that every man shall hear the fulness of the gospel in his own tongue, and in his own language, through those who are ordained unto this power, by the administration of the Comforter, shed forth upon them for the revelation of Jesus Christ." (Doctrine and Covenants 90:11) Having something taught in your own language allows people to better understand the message delivered. While some languages cannot be written--there are many African languages and the language of the natives in Australia that do not have written dialects--the LDS Church is doing their best to communicate with every nation in their own language.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has ***nothing*** to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)